# Does anyone know more about the 1958 Heinkel-211 project?

Tags: aviation-history, jet, experimental-aircraft

Industria Aeronáutica Argentina worked in the 50s in a Jet airliner, Kurt Tank design, the IA-36, 'Cóndor', with simmilarities to 1958 Heinkel-211 project, turbines intake aspirating fuselage boundary layer as some Messerschmitt wartime fighter projects, eg, Me P-1110.
Impossible finding web info about Heinkel airplane, image is from 'Flaps' an Spanish magazine for young aviation enthousiasts. More info?

Blessings +

[image: IA-36 Cóndor][image: Me P-1110][image: IA-36 Cóndor mockup][image: Sud Aviation 'Caravelle']

Comment: I have read about it in Ernst Heinkel's biography where it is briefly mentioned. The German Wikipedia also has a brief [entry](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinkel_He_211). The project was cancelled when no government funding for the development could be obtained.

Answer (score 3):

From 'Flying' magazine, July 1962.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

German Wikipedia has some further details:

https://de-m-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/Heinkel_He_211?_x_tr_sl=de&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp

Interesting concept, especially fascinating that you can't see any engines at first glance. But it would have had issues with maintenance (difficult access to the engines) and safety (an uncontained failure of one engine would have been very likely to affect the second one too), so it's maybe better that it was never built...

Comment: About an engine failure, they said same about Concorde, Tu-144, XB-70. Never Happened. Servicing this type of engine arrangement has no reasons to be harder than for a Phantom. The ring air intake will suck boundary layer, reducing drag. I see nothing but advantages in this idea. Blessings +

Comment: It happened several times with the IL-62 however, which had 4 engines mounted in pairs on either side of the tail section (LOT flights 7 and 5055 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-62#Incidents_and_accidents). Concorde was a very well maintained prestige project, the Tu-144 had so many problems that it only ever flew one route with one flight per week, and the XB-70 was an experimental bomber of which 2 were built and only flown for 5 years.

Comment: Not only Il-62, but VC-10 had same 4 engines arranged as in Caravelle, DC-9. I'd say your concerns proved not realistic. Blessings +